# Are forward proxies secure when SSL/TLS resource is requested?

Tags: http-proxy

I set https://tinyproxy.github.io/ in a rented VPS in another country. Now I can access some resources granted to the IP range associated with that country.

As I understand ISP + a forward proxy sees everything for plain HTTP protocol.

That about HTTPS protocol? Will a browser send request to proxy server unencrypted? Will a forward proxy see the request / response content (my cookies / credentials)?

I assume that no one installed MITM certificate, will the browser detect session SSL intercepted over forward proxy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is it possible to do TLS through proxy without anyone noticing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115762/how-is-it-possible-to-do-tls-through-proxy-without-anyone-noticing), [Can a HTTP proxy see HTTPS traffic?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/262816/can-a-http-proxy-see-https-traffic), [Does a http proxy (ziproxy/squid) encrypt communication between client and server](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/253951/does-a-http-proxy-ziproxy-squid-encrypt-communication-between-client-and-serve)